# Redirect home to another page with htaccess

Tags: redirect, urls, htaccess, rewrite-rules, homepage

I have a page which is called `/home` and I would like to make my `.htaccess` redirect it to `/homepage` which is the actual page that I want to show.

My `.htaccess` has the following:

```
# Switch rewrite engine off in case this was installed under HostPay.
RewriteEngine Off

SetEnv DEFAULT_PHP_VERSION 55

DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

What do I have to add whenever a user tries to go to `http://example.com/`
to redirect them at `http://example.com/homepage`?

Comment: Why not just set this page as the front page through WordPress Settings?
See [Creating a Static Front Page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page)

Comment: @OmarSoliman hey man, i tried but the theme must have some settings that i can't see and it still shows the "Home" page....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to your `.htaccess`, in between the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /home /homepage
Redirect 301 / /homepage
```

However, as [Omar](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/69536/omar-soliman) suggested, you can change your homepage through your [dashboard] by doing the following:

- Go to **Settings** > **Reading**
- Under **Front page displays**, select **A static page (select below)**
- Next to **Front page:** select the page for your new homepage from the dropdown menu
- Click **Save Changes**

[image: Change the front page settings in WordPress]

Comment: Yeap that worked. Although as i told Omar i made this change with no luck.. that's why i asked for htaccess :D

Comment: I see. Sounds like there may be a plugin that is interfering, I'd disable each one and narrow it down.